Which wood is this kitchen counter edge trim?
This counter edge trim is in need of replacement. Which wood is this? Seems like it's going to be tricky to find a proper match. The same wood (Cherry/Oak/etc) appear different per brand.
Seems a roll of "edge tape" is what's needed.



Wood id questions might be shunned around here… check the tour. But, the counter edge looks like cherry to me. And the drawer/ face frame looks like oak. So basically pick whatever you like, and as long as you do all of it, it’ll look great.

A roll of edge tape is a good path to having the same problem in a few years. Routing the edge for solid wood trim is a method to solve the problem on a longer-term basis, or to ensure that having solved the problem for the long term, someone decides it's time to rip out all the cabinets and replace them with something else...
